# Accessing record name and function in generics

Tags: haskell, generics

I am trying to figure out how to do generic deriving modeled after `deriveJSON`. I defined a simple type using record style data constructor as below:

```
data T = C1 { aInt::Int, aString::String} deriving (Show,Generic)
```

What I will like to do is to define a generic derivable function that takes the data constructors above, and outputs a builder using the record names and the functions - just a toy code - we want to make `ABuilder` generic so we can use it for any data type with record syntax (like `deriveJSON` in `Aeson`):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import GHC.Generics

data T = C1 { aInt::Int, aString::String} deriving (Show,Generic)

-- Some kind of builder output - String here is a stand-in for the
-- builder
class ABuilder a where
  f :: a -> String

-- Need to get the record field name, and record field function 
-- for each argument, and build string - for anything that is not 
-- a string, we need to add show function - we assume "Show" instance 
-- exists
instance ABuilder T where
  f x = ("aInt:" ++ (show . aInt $ x)) ++ "," ++ ("aString:" ++ (aString $ x))
```

What I can't figure out is how to get the record name, and the function. Here is my attempt in `ghci 7.10.3`. I could get the data type name, but can't figure out how to get record names and functions out of it.

```
$ ghci Test.hs 
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> datatypeName . from $ (C1 {aInt=1,aString="a"})
"T"
*Main> :t from (C1 {aInt=1,aString="a"})
from (C1 {aInt=1,aString="a"})
  :: D1
       Main.D1T
       (C1
          Main.C1_0T
          (S1 Main.S1_0_0T (Rec0 Int) :*: S1 Main.S1_0_1T (Rec0 String)))
       x
*Main>
```

I will appreciate pointers on how to get the record name and the function in `Generics`. If `TemplateHaskell` is better approach for defining `Generic` instance of `ABuilder`, I will appreciate hearing why. I am hoping to stick to `Generics` for solving this at compile-time if the solution is simple. I have noticed that `Aeson` uses `TemplateHaskell` for `deriveJSON` part. That is why my question about `TemplateHaskell` above to see if there is something I am missing here (I am using `ghc 7.10.3` and don't need backward compatibility with older versions).

Comment: When you derive `Generic`, the generated types that represent metadata (ie. `C1_0T`, `S1_0_0T`, etc) have instances of the appropriate classes (`Datatype`, `Constructor`, `Selector`). These instances are what allow you to access this metadata. You will need a class to handle the different generic constructors, as in all the generics examples.

Comment: @user2407038, yep, I know. My question is about how to access record names and functions. Generic examples that I have seen so far don't have those scenarios.

Comment: There is no magic - call the methods of the typeclasses, i.e [`Selector`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html#t:Selector) on the appropriate values. The same exact way you have used `datatypeName`. You haven't provided any code so it's hard to say any more.

Comment: Use the source, Luke! Hackage is an *invaluable* resource for learning how to write Haskell. If you want to know how to do something "like `aeson`", the `aeson` source code should be the very first place you look. Fortunately, `aeson` has pretty readable source, so you should be able to go pretty far that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something I just whipped up that should get this if you hand it the innards of a specific constructor:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, TypeOperators, FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances #-}

import GHC.Generics

data T = C1 { aInt::Int, aString::String} deriving (Show,Generic)

class AllSelNames x where
    allSelNames :: x -> [String]

instance (AllSelNames (a p), AllSelNames (b p)) => AllSelNames ((a :*: b) p) where
    allSelNames (x :*: y) = allSelNames x ++ allSelNames y

instance Selector s => AllSelNames (M1 S s f a) where
    allSelNames x = [selName x]
```

From the repl we see

```
*Main> let x = unM1 . unM1 $ from (C1 {aInt=1,aString="a"})
*Main> allSelNames x
["aInt","aString"]
```

Comment: thank you for taking time to answer this. To extract the record function `aInt`, would it suffice to pattern match on `M1 {unM1 = K1 {unK1 = 1}}`, and take `unK1`?

Comment: That gives you the value, not the function. Bear in mind this works if you have atomic things in the leaves of the records, if they're complex structures themselves, you'll need to `to` them back to turn them back to normal data from their `Rep`.